# R Update Single Vector Element from Function

Tags: r, vector, scope, mutability

I am relatively new to R, and have come across a situation that confuses me. I was updating some values in a vector that I initialized beforehand, and realized that the values were not updating. After spending a couple hours trying to debug, I come here.

The minimal code can be summarized like this:

```r
incr <- function(v) {
    v[1] = v[1] + 1
}

vec = 0

incr(vec)
```

Why would I make an increment function? I had a vector meant to store counts for each type of customly defined categories, and would switch on some factors to tell which counter to increment. But ultimately this code is the fundamental idea that's at the core of it.

The behaviour I expect is that `vec[1]`'s value be changed from 0 to 1.
However `vec[1]` remains at 0 when looking at it in the debugger. Is this because of some scope or mutability thing I haven't read about?

Comment: Updating a variable in global environment from inside the function is generally not recommended. You could define your function as  `incr <- function(v) v + 1` and save the changed output while calling it. `vec = 0;vec <- incr(vec)`

Comment: But what if vec was length of, say, 5? I would still only want to increment vec[1]

Comment: There are lot of ways to deal with it. You can do `vec[1] <- incr(vec[1])`. Or change the function to `incr <- function(v) v[1] + 1` and do `vec[1] <- incr(vec)`.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assign` to set a value to a variable name in the environment of your choice. In the function below, the default environment is the caller's environment.

```
incr <- function(x, envir = parent.frame()){
  xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  x[1] <- x[1] + 1L
  assign(xname, x, envir = envir)
}
a <- 0L
incr(a)
a
#[1] 1
incr(a)
a
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I would have never thought to use the `assign` function.